# How to find the PDF version of a Read-the-docs project

Tags: read-the-docs

What am I not seeing? The [RTD features](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#pdf-generation) page says:

> PDF Generation
>
> When you build your project on RTD, we automatically build a PDF of
>   your project’s documentation. We also build them for every version
>   that you upload, so we can host the PDFs of your latest documentation,
>   as well as your latest stable releases as well.

But how do you find the PDF version? A websearch finds this [2012 blog post](http://natanyellin.com/2012/04/22/downloading-pdf-documentation-for-readthedocs-projects/) where the writer says:

> Here, for example, is the url to Django-Tastypie’s PDF docs:
>
> ```
> http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-tastypie/latest/django-tastypie.pdf
> ```
>
> You can replace django-tastypie with the slug for any Read the Docs
>   project.

However, RTD doesn't permit users to browse the website's directory tree via the URL: `http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/[project slug]/`, get's me `403 FORBIDDEN`! At least for project CookieCutter.

Comment: readthedocs does not support pdf download for mkdocs projects; that's a lot of projects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For security reasons, many websites do not allow you to browse directory listings on the web server; hence the 403.

Anyway, I guess you were looking for these:

- https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cookiecutter/latest/cookiecutter.pdf
- https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cookiecutter/stable/cookiecutter.pdf

Typically, it should not be necessary to construct this URL yourself. There is a link in the navigation bar of RtD. You just have to know where to find it.

[image: RtD screenshot, panel collapsed]

Notice the 'Read the Docs' label at the bottom left of the page (together with the version indicator). Click it and a panel will open.

[image: RtD screenshot, panel expanded]

In the panel, you can select the desired version. The 'PDF' link navigates to the PDF file. The build system of RtD should automatically keep this file up to date with the documentation source.

**Note:**
for PDF and EPUB generation to be available, the RtD project:

- must use [Sphinx](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html) as its documentation generator; not [MkDocs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/getting-started-with-mkdocs.html)
- must be configured to [enable PDF and EPUB builds](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html#enabling-pdf-and-epub-builds)

Comment: [how to download the docs as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130181/how-to-download-the-docs-as-pdf)  link is broken.

Comment: this site https://krotov.readthedocs.io/en/stable/01_overview.html also doesn't have PDF option. But I don't think so it is because " some websites that host their own copy of RtD" ,  since it is an open-source project. So why do you think it does not have a PDf version?

Comment: How to get the panel in local build? I dont see this option locally.

Comment: PDF/EPUB support depends on the project, not on the version of RtD (my earlier assumption). I fixed the last paragraph of my answer; hope it's correct now.

Answer (score 1):

I find the `Read the Docs` label that opens a panel with a pdf link preferable.  However, if that isn't present, an alternative is doing a web search for it.

e.g., search for
`readthedocs cookiecutter pdf`
and the first result I see (as of 8 July 2020) is a link to the pdf: https://readthedocs.org/projects/cookiecutter/downloads/pdf/latest/

As of 8 Jul 2020, the [cookiecutter readthedocs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/) does indeed have expandable panel with the pdf link.  However,
when I look at the [readthedocs for pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), there is no `ReadTheDocs` clickable to open a panel. But if I search Google for
`readthedocs pipenv pdf`
the first result is a link to the pdf: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pipenv/latest/pipenv.pdf